# Using directive output in Drective Composition API

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular2-directives

The [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/directive-composition-api#including-inputs-and-outputs) show that you can use Directive Composition API even when directive has outputs. However, it seems that directive's outputs become component's outputs. I'd like to use directive's output within the component to which I'm attaching the directive. Is there any way to do that?

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'admin-menu',
  template: 'admin-menu.html',
  hostDirectives: [{
    directive: MenuBehavior,
    inputs: ['menuId'],
    outputs: ['menuClosed'],
  }],
})
export class AdminMenu {

  someMethod() {
    // use menuClosed here....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hostListener` decorator to listen `hostDirectives` output.

```
export class AdminMenu {
  @HostListener('menuClosed',['$event']) onMenuClosed(e:{closed:boolean}){
    console.log('Closed',e);
  }
}
```

**[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hbuk1r?file=admin.ts)**

Answer (score 1):

I am able to import the directive through the constructor, since its binded to the element!

Just to make sure I created two directives and its working fine!

binded component html

```
<p>test works!</p>
<br /><br /><br />
test directive output {{ output }} <br /><br /><br /><br />

<br />
qwerty directive output {{ output1 }}<br /><br /><br /><br />
```

binded component ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { QwertyDirective } from '../qwerty.directive';
import { TestDirective } from '../test.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  standalone: true,
  hostDirectives: [
    {
      directive: TestDirective,
      inputs: ['menuId'],
      outputs: ['emitter'],
    },
    {
      directive: QwertyDirective,
      inputs: ['menuId'],
      outputs: ['emitter'],
    },
  ],
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css'],
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('menuId') menuId!: string;
  @Output() emitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  output = '';
  output1 = '';
  constructor(
    private testDir: TestDirective,
    private qwertyDir: QwertyDirective
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.testDir.emitter.subscribe((val: any) => {
      this.output = val;
    });
    this.qwertyDir.emitter.subscribe((val: any) => {
      this.output1 = val;
    });
  }
}
```

directive

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
@Directive({
  selector: '[appTest]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class TestDirective {
  @Input('menuId') menuId!: string;
  @Output() emitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  constructor() {
    interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
      this.emitter.emit(Math.random() + ' ' + this.menuId);
    });
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { QwertyDirective } from './qwerty.directive';
import { TestDirective } from './test.directive';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [TestDirective, TestComponent, QwertyDirective],
  template: `
    <app-test [menuId]="name" (emitter)="emitter($event)"></app-test>

    output {{output}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  output = '';
  output1 = '';

  emitter(event: any) {
    this.output = event;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nbhma2?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Ftest.directive.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.ts,src%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.html,src%2Fqwerty.directive.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Interesting example, thanks. I did not know that when you inject the directive into component, it will inject the same instance as the one used on the host.

Comment: @mnj as I posted this answer, i saw the one below it and it looks cleaner, go for the second approach if you want cleaner code :) the second one is the cleaner correct answer